# Outlook: Attach a file with a dynamic name

Tags: vba, outlook

Argh, Object doesn't support this property or method error 438!

I haven't tried this but, I think it might work:

```
objFS.System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName)
if objFS.System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName) = "VS12_WID1" Then 
fileName = AFile.Name
getFileName = filePath & "/" & fileName
```

I should simplfy it more then try to rename the file.

```
Sub AddAttachment()
Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim getFile, fileName, filePath As String


Set filePath = "F:\"
Set fileName = "V_W_*_*_.pdf"
Set getFile = "filePath" & "fileName"
Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = MyApp.CreateItem(0)
Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments

With myItem
.To = "email@mail.com"
.CC = ""
.Subject = "test"
myAttachments.Add getFile
.ReadReceiptRequested = False
.HTMLBody = "Report(s) Attached"
End With
myItem.Send
End Sub
```

I'm getting a compile error: Object required highlighting both Sub AddAttachment() and Set filePath.  I feel so close to making this work!

UPDATED CODE:

```
Sub AddAttachment()
Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim getFileName, fileName, filePath As String
Dim objFS: Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set filePath = "F:\"
Set getFileName = filePath & fileName
Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = MyApp.CreateItem(0)
Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments

For Each fileName In filePath
    If fcase(objFS.GetExtensionName(fileName)) = "VS111111_WID111A" Then
        fileName = "VS111111_WID111A.pdf"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

With myItem
.To = "email@mail.com"
.CC = ""
.Subject = ""
myAttachments.Add getFileName
.ReadReceiptRequested = False
.HTMLBody = "Report(s) Attached"
End With
myItem.Send
End Sub
```

I have enough knowledge to read the script to understand what is going on.  The code I made can only find a fixed file name. How can the file name be made dynamic?

```
Sub AddAttachment()
Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = MyApp.CreateItem(0)
Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments

With myItem
.To = "email@address.com"
.CC = "email@address.com"
.Subject = ""
myAttachments.Add "F:\constantFilenameHas8char_constantFilenameHas7char_variableHas5Int_todaysModifiedDate_variableHas6Int.pdf"
.ReadReceiptRequested = False
.HTMLBody = "Report(s) Attached"
End With
myItem.Send
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not clear on how you want to get the filename.Think of using 
a variable and pass the filepath and name as you required.

dim FileToAttach as string

FileToAttach ="FilePath" & "Filename"

myAttachments.Add FileToAttach

For your updated code

Sub AddAttachment()

Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments

Dim getFileName, filename

Dim filePath As Object

Dim objFS As FileSystemObject

Set objFS = New FileSystemObject

Set filePath = objFS.GetFolder("C:\Users\Dinesh\Desktop\")

Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set myItem = MyApp.CreateItem(0)

Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments

For Each AFile In filePath.Files

Debug.Print UCase(objFS.GetExtensionName(fileName))
    
If UCase(objFS.GetExtensionName(AFile)) = "PDF" Then
        
fileName = AFile.Name
        
getFileName = filePath & "/" & fileName
    
Exit For
    
End If

Next

With myItem

.To = ""

.CC = ""

.Subject = ""

myAttachments.Add getFileName

.ReadReceiptRequested = False

.HTMLBody = "Report(s) Attached"

.Display

End With

'myItem.Send

End Sub

Comment: I tested this and it only attaches the first file that has the extension "pdf".  I will keep trying to create code that will search for a file with a specific naming convention.

Comment: Sweet! I can use GetFileName or GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method Method! Yay!

Comment: I can do a work around with your current code, too!  Thank you so much!